# pandas merge does weird job if left and right df's keys are different

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have found pandas merge method does weird job if key index of left and right are different.

for instances, I define left and right dataframes as follow

left_df

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  2  1  2  3  4
1  2  3  2  3  4  5
2  1  2  3  4  5  6
3  2  2  4  5  6  7
4  2  3  5  6  7  8
```

right_df

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
1  1  2  3  4  5  7
2  2  3  4  5  6  7
3  2  3  4  5  6  8
```

and do merge job with a few parameters,

```
pd.merge(left_df, right_df, how="inner", left_on = [0,1], right_on=[0,1], indicator=False)
```

the result is find as expected.

```
       0  1  2_x  3_x  4_x  5_x  2_y  3_y  4_y  5_y
    0  1  2    1    2    3    4    3    4    5    6
    1  1  2    1    2    3    4    3    4    5    7
    2  1  2    3    4    5    6    3    4    5    6
    3  1  2    3    4    5    6    3    4    5    7
    4  2  3    2    3    4    5    4    5    6    7
    5  2  3    2    3    4    5    4    5    6    8
    6  2  3    5    6    7    8    4    5    6    7
    7  2  3    5    6    7    8    4    5    6    8
```

But if I set left_on and right_on params differently, result becomes very weird like below.

```
merge job with '1,2' left key index

pd.merge(left_df, right_df, how="inner", left_on = [1,2], right_on=[0,1], indicator=False)


   1  2  0_x  1_x  2_x  3_x  4_x  5_x  0_y  1_y  2_y  3_y  4_y  5_y
0  2  3    1    2    3    4    5    6    2    3    4    5    6    7
1  2  3    1    2    3    4    5    6    2    3    4    5    6    8

                ^    ^                   ^    ^
                 these columns are duplicated.

   0_x    1    2  3_x  4_x  5_x  2_y  3_y  4_y  5_y
0    1    2    3    4    5    6    4    5    6    7
1    1    2    3    4    5    6    4    5    6    8
this is what I expected. (keys of each df are removed.)
```

are there any parameter or ways to solve above weird job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wondered a condition that the weird result occurs I mentioned, So I divide my own assumption into two cases.

- **When column name of each key is different**
- **When column index (In this case, absolute column position in data frame.) of each key is different**

By some test cases, I could figure out **When column name of each key is different,** result is not so good.

So this problem can easily be handled chaning columns name.

```
left_df
   0  key0  key1  3  4  5
0  1     2     1  2  3  4
1  2     3     2  3  4  5
2  1     2     3  4  5  6
3  2     2     4  5  6  7
4  2     3     5  6  7  8

right_df
   key0  key1  2  3  4  5
0     1     2  3  4  5  6
1     1     2  3  4  5  7
2     2     3  4  5  6  7
3     2     3  4  5  6  8

result
   0  key0  key1  3_x  4_x  5_x  2  3_y  4_y  5_y
0  1     2     3    4    5    6  4    5    6    7
1  1     2     3    4    5    6  4    5    6    8
```

And below is simple code implementation.

```
        key_entry = []
        for i in range(len([1,2])):
            key_entry.append('key' + str(i))

        left_rename_map = {}
        for i, each in zip([1,2], key_entry):
            left_rename_map[i] = each

        right_rename_map = {}
        for i, each in zip([0,1], key_entry):
            right_rename_map[i] = each

        df1 = df1.rename(columns=left_rename_map)
        df2 = df2.rename(columns=right_rename_map)
```

In my opinion, Pandas try to save all column information(in this case, column name). Therefore If column name of keys are different, Pandas thinks that column is not same and it doesn't remove key columns though every value is same that column has.